# Splitting and copying csv fields in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have a csv file for eg

ID,Name,products

101,Tesco,Apple;Banana;Oranges

102,Lidl,Juice;Yogurt

103,Aldi,Fruits;vegetables;rice

Using the pandas library I want to split these into a new csv such that for the products column there is only one value for every field

The following code I've tried only selects those particular column and writes the values to a new csv. I want to modify the output.

```
df=pd.read_csv('final.csv',delimiter=",", index_col="ID",encoding="ISO- 
8859-1")
df1=df[,"Name","Products"]
df1.to_csv('a.csv',header='True')
print (df1)
```

I want the new csv generated to have the values in the following format-

101,Tesco,Apple

101,Tesco,Banana

101,Tesco,Oranges

102,Lidl,Juice

102,Lidl,Yogurt

103,Aldi,Fruits

..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: There's probably a way to do it without creating the list column, but using Wen-Ben's  `unnesting` function it would be `unnesting(df.assign(products = df.products.str.split(';')), ['products'])`

Comment: this is a little bit different because the desired output is actually extra rows not columns

Comment: Im not creating extra columns, just that most typical unnesting questions have the input as a list of items, not a delimited string. so to work with most solutions need to first transform `'Apple;Banana;Oranges'` to `['Apples', 'Banana', 'Oranges']`. The result is each element split to a new row. There's perhaps a dup that deals with unnesting strings directly, but using `.str.split` is trivial enough to get it in the desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can:

1) Split the items in each row with delimiter ";". Then we get one column for each item.

2) We then unstack the columns to get them as rows, and then remove the index level that is added based on the previous column values.

3) Name this pd.Series and join on the main df.

```
prod = df['products'].str.split(";", expand=True).unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).dropna()

    ID
    101         Apple
    102         Juice
    103        Fruits
    101        Banana
    102        Yogurt
    103    vegetables
    101       Oranges
    103          rice

prod.name = 'product'

df = df.join(prod.to_frame())
df.drop('products', axis=1, inplace=True)

Output:

      Name     product
ID                    
101  Tesco       Apple
101  Tesco      Banana
101  Tesco     Oranges
102   Lidl       Juice
102   Lidl      Yogurt
103   Aldi      Fruits
103   Aldi  vegetables
103   Aldi        rice
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution. I have a question.. what if there is some redundancy of data values in certain rows like
1,Tesco,Apple,Banana,Apple,oranges
In this case i would only want one of the "apples" and unique columns values like
1 Tesco apple
1 Tesco banana
1 Tesco Orange

what modifications would be made then?

Comment: If you want unique product values for each ID, you can group by ID and then drop_duplicates. So, if you do this on the prod series: prod.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())

Comment: I tried it out and ran the code,but it didnt seem to work

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: It still didnt remove the duplicates, could you kindly show the updated code above in your answer

Comment: prod.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates()) outputs a new pd.Series, it does not change prod. Did you set prod = prod.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())?